# Bool value not changed after Push

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I have a problem with a `BOOL`, when I try to change the value of an another view's `BOOL` but it is not working.

**The declaration of `BOOL` :**

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL vuesortie;`

**Assigning `vuesortie` in `view` :**

```
premierview *vcc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"jeux"];
SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;
premierview *view;//  I'm really sorry not to be a robot and do shit

if ([cellchoistxt  isEqual: @"Déjà sortie"])
{
    [view setVuesortie:YES];
    [revealController pushFrontViewController:vcc animated:YES];       
} else if ([cellchoistxt isEqual: @"Prochaines sorties"]) {
    NSLog(@"////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    [view setVuesortie:NO];
    [revealController pushFrontViewController:vcc animated:YES];
}
```

**And the code when view is loaded after `pushFrontViewController` :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%hhd" , vuesortie); //--> value = 0 in all cases
    ....
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to set `premierview *view`?

Comment: You don't actually create an instance of `view`, therefore attempting to assign any of its properties has no effect.

Comment: @Ra1nWarden Yes I forgot...

Answer (score 1):

```
premierview *view;
```

is not initialized.

You have to initizialized your view before (and please use another class name like "**PremierView**"):

In any case if for `premier view` you mean your viewController `vcc` you should to do:

```
[vcc setVuesortie:YES];
```

and obviously the class `premierview` contains the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL vuesortie;
```

You have to study concept of **OOP** because you must understand that if you want point to the property of your instanced `viewController` you have to set the value in your `vcc` object.

Finally please, use correct notation, like for example:

```
`PremierViewController` and not `premier view`
```

for 2 reasons:

1. is not a `UIView` but a `UIViewController` and so is correct maintain the end with `ViewController` rather than `View`;
2. use **camel notation**, so capitalize the first letter of each word.

Comment: Yes I forgot to initialize view but the problem don't come only from that... I don't understand reaction of community.

Comment: reactions come because from your code attached with your question, the community understand that you are not a developer who at least studied the basic stuff. This community should be useful to find solution to troubles and new implementations, but the community assumes that who is writing has a real problem or question, and not BIG GAPS on basilar development. You didn't forget to initialize the variable, you didn't know what you was doing man...you know.

Comment: I forgot YES I forgot.

Comment: So your idea was have a `premierview *vcc` and have a `premierview *view` then set the `bool` on the `view` (suppose that was initialized) and then open the `vcc`? Doesn't make sense..it's obvious that you wanted set the bool on `vcc` but for some reason you declared `view` and tried to do something there. No worries man, i suggest you to take a good Objective-C book, but that start from the basis of `OOP` (`Object Oriented Programming`) and read it with relax and passion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you never assign anything to the view variable. When you call [view setVueSortie] the view object is nil.